# How not to set DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity for Seed entities

Tags: .net, entity-framework, code-first

We had BaseEntity defined as following:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        ...
}
```

As a result of Ids were genereated by DB. However, now we are going to add Seed data. I added the following Seed code:

```
            Country c = new Country()
            {
                Id = new Guid("251D06A5-E864-4B9F-803B-00E409B0F5AB"),
                Name = "Oceania",
                RegionType = RegionTypeEnum.Region,
                ParentCountryId = worldId
            };
            AddOrUpdate(c);
```

In this case my "Id" was ignored and new Id was generated. Thus Seeds always created new countries.

Thus I do not need database to generate Id (but I want to use BaseEntity as base class) for this entity. I wish to have Ids defined in code for this entity.

How do you suggest to deal with this?

Answer (score 2):

There is an overload method for AddOrUpdate where you can specify what property should be taken into consideration to decide if it should add the entity or not.

> The AddOrUpdate method supplies some overloads which allows you to supply a Func expression as the first parameter which allows you to give EF an expression to evaluate whether an Add or an Update should be run.  My final code looks as follows:

```
   context.Departments.AddOrUpdate(
    d => d.Name,
    new Department() { Name = "English" },
    new Department() { Name = "Maths" },
    new Department() { Name = "French" }
);
```

> This now works as expected as the comparison is performed on the Name column only.

Source: http://www.gregpakes.co.uk/post/using-addordelete-to-seed-data-without-the-key-column

Comment: Maybe this would fix one part of my problem, but still I wish to have Ids defined in code for this entity. End this is the question - how to define Ids in code for this entity?

Comment: If your column is indentified as identity column in your database, it will always generate an id, at least that's my experience.

Comment: Ok, but what is the solution then? This doesn't feel ok for me.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea. Maybe you should start your Seed method with disabling the Identity of your Id-column and ending the method with reenabling the identity at the end of your method.

I have no experience with that but you can check these SQL-commands. You can execute them via the method ExecuteSqlCommand().

`SET IDENTITY_INSERT tablename ON`
`SET IDENTITY_INSERT tablename OFF`

Pay attention to the fact that the words ON/OFF reference to the SQL statements ability to insert their own identity value.